# How can I specify path to jtl files when I want to publish graph (from jmeter-graph-maven-plugin) in teamcity?

Tags: teamcity, jmeter-maven-plugin

I use *jmeter-maven-plugin* (version 1.10.0) to run JMeter test - first I run it from IntelliJ, then from TeamCity (for both - command: *mvn jmeter-graph:create-graph*)

When I want to use the following configuration for *jmeter-graph-maven-plugin*:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-graph-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <configuration>                           
        <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/*.jtl</inputFile>
        <graphs>
            <graph>
                 <pluginType>TransactionsPerSecond</pluginType>
                 <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/TPS.png</outputFile>
            </graph>
        </graphs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

it works from IntelliJ, but in TeamCity I get:
*ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find specified JTL file: /project/XX/opt/team-city-8.0.5/buildAgent/work/xxxxx/JMeter/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl*

Result file exists (and it is previous used in *xml-maven-plugin* - even configuration is *.jtl - xml plugin works correctly in TeamCity).

When I use specific file name (so e.g. *20150317test-result.jtl* instead of *.jtl) it works also from TeamCity.
How can I use general file name? Or maybe there is an option in *jmeter-maven-plugin* to define some fixed jtl file name (and then use it in *jmeter-graph-maven-plugin*)?

Comment: We are going to need some console output to have an idea of what is going on.  are the results file being generated as part of the build?  If so what phase are the results being generated and what phase is the graph maven plugin running in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did workaround for this issue.
I changed jmeter-graph-maven-plugin configuration to:

```
<inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/${fileName}.jtl</inputFile>
```

and now I run it using *mvn jmeter-graph:create-graph -DfileName=%profile%* (where profile name is the same as jmx test file).