# How to change result file name (of jtl file) in jmeter-maven-plugin?

Tags: jmeter-maven-plugin

I use `jmeter-maven-plugin (version 1.10.0)` to run **JMeter** test. I want to change default name of the result file, so I want to change argument for `option -l (logfile)`:

```
    [debug] JMeter is called with the following command line arguments: -n 
    -t C:\XX\JMeter\src\test\jmeter\some-test.jmx 
    -l C:\XX\JMeter\target\jmeter\results\20150323-some-test.jtl 
    -d C:\XX\JMeter\target\jmeter 
    -j C:\XX\JMeter\target\jmeter\logs\some-test.jmx.log
```

Edited:
I run it from IntelliJ using: *mvn integration-test -Prun-some-test*

I have defined two profiles (for two different test files):

```
<profile>
    <id>run-some-test</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFilesIncluded>
                                <jMeterTestFile>some-test.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                            </testFilesIncluded>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>run-another-test</id>
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFilesIncluded>
                                <jMeterTestFile>another-test.jmx</jMeterTestFile>
                            </testFilesIncluded>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: OK, so… do that. Where exactly are you getting stuck?

Comment: I don't know if the file name is some property in configuration? (like in https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't.**

The test name is used to create the log name.  So as an example if your test name was:

> some-test.jmx

Your log name will always be:

> some-test.log

The reason that you cannot change the log names is that each <jMeterTestFile> specified in the <testFilesIncluded> block is actually used as a REGEX internally.  A normal file name (as you have specified above) is a valid REGEX which is why it works.

Due to the fact that each <jMeterTestFile> is a REGEX we don't know how many files it will return so we can't make a one-to-one mapping between a <jMeterTestFile> and a log file.

To keep things simple and prevent problems we hard code the log file name as specified above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I have another question (related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121450/how-can-i-specify-path-to-jtl-files-when-i-want-to-publish-graph-from-jmeter-gr?rq=1) - I have some profiles with different jmx test file to execution. After it I use _jmeter-graph-maven-plugin_ to create graphs, but in configuration of that plugin I have  
         <inputFile>${project.build.directory}/jmeter/results/some-test.jtl</inputFile>  
Name of the input file depends on profile (and execution date) - how can I configure this plugin to make graph from the right file?

Comment: You'll need to know the names of the JMX files you are putting into src/test/jmeter because you know that the log files will match the name of these files.  You can then specify the names of the .jtl files that will be produced by JMeter for the graph plugin.

Comment: I updated my question (there are two profiles with different files). So in src/test/jmeter I've got two files and depend on profile I run one of them. Now - how can I specify in _jmeter-graph-maven-plugin_ that I want to use specific jtl file (related to jmx defined in profile)?